About my 4year old
My 4year old just started stealing food ,I have told him many times not to take things without asking instead he does...what can I do to make him understand that stealing is wrong

Welcome to the site.  Were always glad to have you, but I'm afraid your question as written now is rather poor quality  You should edit it to give it a title that describes your issue so people know what is being asked before opening the question, something like "how to stop 4 yr old from stealing food"  You're tagging could also use work.  3-4 would be pre-schooler not toddler so that tag is wrong.  You would also want to add as many tags as relevant, so the discipline tag should also apply.  Finally more specifics about your situation in the body would make it easier to give relevant answers
